# Popup function in jquery

Tags: jquery, popup, append

Case: I'm appending different profiles with a picture, name, age and gender inside an html-section. (Think Tinder, but showing 10-ish profiles at once.) I want a function that makes a popup with 'newInterests' printed out in a p-tag, specific to each profile. If you click a button or if you click the profile-picture isnt that important.

I cant find any way to do this, maybe you guys have a solution? :) Thanks in advance!

Note: Appending the profiles work. I'm able to show pictures with names and such, I just can't find a way to implement a popup specific to each profile.

Note 2: let newInterests = profileInterests = profile.description; Prints out the variable. I just want it to be included in a popup.

HTML:

```
<section id="profileSection">


</section>
```

JS:

```
$("#showAllMenBtn").click(function(){   

          $("#profileSection").html("");

          $(maleProfiles).each(function(index, profile){

               let profileImg = $("<img>", {src:`${profile.imageSrc}`});            
               let newName = profileName = profile.name;
               let newAge = profileAge = profile.age;
               let newGender = profileGender = profile.gender;
               //let newInterests = profileInterests = profile.description;     


               $("#profileSection").append(profileImg, newName, newAge, newGender);
          })

 });
```

I get everything from a JSON module, which you can see here:

[image]

Comment: You can program a whole modals library, or if you're using something like Bootstrap or Foundation they provide all of that functionality for you

Comment: unfortunately, I cant use any of that and I'm trying to find a way to do this with regular jquery only.

Comment: Well you'll be wanting a fixed / absolutely positioned Div that displays a modal (popup window) which is generated when a user clicks on a profile. You would also want to have something that maintains the list of open modals, and handles things like closing modals for you. Plenty of tutorials online, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp